# Find the definer of a view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, migrate

I have moved a database that contains views from one machine to another, and now the views have become broken.  I know I need to recreate the old user on the new machine in order to fix it, but my question is:

How do I find out the username of the old user that created the view?  I no longer have access to the old machine.

Thanks.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/how-do-i-change-the-definer-of-a-view-in-mysql

Answer (score 9):

Use the command `SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname`
You may see further information in 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-view.html

Comment: "#1356 - View 'database.table' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them" - this is why I need to change the definer, which is why I need to find out what the definer's name is! :)

Comment: even account with SUPER privilege like root ?

Comment: Yes - on the new machine root is actually the only user I have set up so far.

Comment: What's your mysql version? I have tested `create view` with normal user in mysql-community-server 5.6.27, and after dropping the normal user and re-login by root user, although warnings are reported. the detail of create view syntax is still shown.
`mysql> show warnings \G
...
  Level: Note
   Code: 1449
Message: The user specified as a definer ('testuser'@'localhost') does not exist
...
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1356
Message: View 'stackoverflow.testview' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
`

Comment: It's version 5.6.16 MySQL Community Server (GPL).  I have worked around the problem for now by just dropping the view and recreating it, but it's not really a solution... :/

Comment: oops.. actually long time ago i have faced similar situation (mysql_upgrade from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5, and finally 5.6, after that truncate the table mysql.user ). afterwards view could not be accessed, and my senior just re-created the view by dropping it and creating it just like what you did  (or `ALTER VIEW`? forgot) ... and he said if it is possible, declare `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` instead of `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` to prevent re-occurrence of similar case.

Answer (score 7):

To see definer of each view, execute:

```
select v.TABLE_SCHEMA, v.TABLE_NAME, v.`DEFINER` 
from information_schema.VIEWS v
where v.TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('sys');
```