# 'The user specified as a definer ('mysqladmin'@'%') does not exist'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, mysql-connector

I have a MVC app connected to a MySQL database. It has been running smoothly for a long time making reading and writing through Entity Framework and also directly by executing SQL-queries. However, I have now encountered a strange thing, since some direct SQL-queries suddenly fails. I get the error: MySqlConnector.MySqlException:
'The user specified as a definer ('mysqladmin'@'%') does not exist'. The strange thing is that mysqladmin has never existed as a user, and in my webconfig-file I specify the user and password for connecting to the db:

add name="CPConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;database=cpdata;uid=root;password=*********;Connect Timeout=30; Allow User Variables=true; UseAffectedRows=True"

I haven't changed any of this, and some queries (both reading and writing) still run as they should, but at least one is giving me this error. Does anyone have any suggestions, what could be the problem?

Thank you.

All the best
Troels

Comment: Simple sql queries do not have a definer clause in mysql. Objects, such as views, procedures, and functions have definer clauses that enable these to run in the name of a different user. You need to check if your app tries to set such objects up.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I looked a little further, and at some point I exported my production db (where the user mysqladmin exists) and imported it into my local developer db (where the user is root). I guess that could be causing the problems, although I don't quite get, why I can do some queries and not others? But where is the mysqladmin user name "hidden" after the import, and how can I change it? Thak you again. /Troels

Comment: My guess is that some of your queries reference objects that have such definer clauses.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. My queries reference three tables, but is there a way in e.g. MySQL Workbench to look for such clauses?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172947/find-the-definer-of-a-view-in-mysql - you have to do similar queries for all other objexts with definers.